# Automatically include a Gem in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working a gem that has some metlhods that I want to include into my controller classes, but I would like it to automatically include itself upon installation. So, for example, `include MyGem`, will not be required.

I tried using a railtie, but I am unsure if that is the right way since it doesn't work as far as I can tell.  It looks similar to:

```
require 'my_gem'

module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "my_gem.method_items" do
   ActionController::Base.send :include, MethodItems
  end
 end
end
```

Any help would be great

Comment: did you try with the full namespace? `ActionController::Base.send :include, MyGem::MethodItems`

Comment: Just tried that after your comment and it still appears not to be working.

Comment: just tested, posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module MyGem
  module InstanceMethods
    def foo
      "bar"
    end
  end
end

module MyGem
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer "testing" do |app|
      ActionController::Base.send :include, MyGem::InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
```

Then in console:

```
ActionController::Base.instance_methods.grep(/foo/)
=> ["foo"]
```

Comment: The Engine worked!!! I believe the behavior falls under the Rails::Engine category...Thank you very much.