# How to require module from gem to use its classes without namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Could you please help me?
I am developing gem, it has a module:

```
#cherry/sdk/high_level.rb
 module Cherry
  module SDK
   module HighLevel
    autoload :CherryUser, 'cherry/sdk/high_level/user'
    autoload :CherryCard, 'cherry/sdk/high_level/card'
   end
  end
 end
```

Now I use it like this:

```
 require "cherry/sdk/high_level"
 user = Cherry::SDK::CherryUser.new
 card = Cherry::SDK::CherryCard.new
```

But I need user to **use my gem classes without namespaces**, i.e.

```
 require "cherry/sdk/high_level"
 user = CherryUser.new
 card = CherryCard.new
```

How can I achieve it?
Also what do you think about **autoload**?
it was promised to depreciate this ability, but new ruby versions still have **autoload** method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always include modules to get access to their classes inside current class scope:

```
module Cherry
  module SDK
    module HighLevel
      class CherryUser
      end
    end
  end
end

# require "cherry/sdk/high_level"
include Cherry::SDK::HighLevel
user = CherryUser.new # => #<Cherry::SDK::HighLevel::CherryUser:0x007f9c09185ab8>
```

About autoload - it's considered bad practice and you should avoid it. Here is quite good article about this: http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Comment: Thank you for your response. But can I set up my gem to allow the user to don't use **include** ? Can **include** be executed automatically in gem?

Comment: you can use rails engine for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066040/automatically-include-a-gem-in-a-controller otherwise I would recommend to stick with good, old include behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you create classes at the top level and inherit them from your namespaced classes, it should work, i.e.

```
#cherry_user.rb
class CherryUser < Cherry::SDK::HighLevel::CherryUser
end

require 'cherry_user'
CherryUser.new
```

Otherwise you might need to define the public interface for your methods in the top-level CherryUser class, that will call the methods you need in your SDK (might be better organization-wise to set up your public API like that)

Also a better practice would be to have

```
#lib/cherry/user.rb
module Cherry
  class User < Cherry::SDK::HighLevel::CherryUser
  end
end

#lib/cherry.rb
require 'cherry/user'

# in user code
Cherry::User.new
```

this way bundler will automatically require lib/cherry.rb which will, in turn, load the User code, also there will be less classes added to the global namespace which is generally good